# How to check intersections buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect

I'm dynamically creating buttons on `UIView`.
I can move them by dragging using this code

```
- (IBAction)draggedOut: (id)sender withEvent: (UIEvent *) event: (NSSet *)touches {
   UIButton *selected = (UIButton *)sender;
   selected.center = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:hallView];
}
```

I can have more then one button. When I'm dragging some button, I need to check are there any intersections with other buttons?

How can I do this?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more general solution if you want to check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cycle through the other buttons in the view and, for each of them, check whether in intersect the dragged one via:

```
CGRectIntersectsRect (draggedButton.frame, anotherButton.frame);
```

You could use a function like:

```
- (BOOL)isThereButtonsIntersectionInView:(UIView *)containerView 
                               forButton:(UIButton *)draggedButton
{
    for(UIView *view in containerView.subviews){
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] &&
            view != draggedButton &&
            CGRectIntersectsRect (view.frame, draggedButton.frame)){

                return YES;
            }
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Call this method passing as a parameter the view containing the buttons and the dragged button.

Answer (score 1):

You can get frames of buttons and check using this

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(firstButton.frame, secondButton.frame))  {
      return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to compare the frame of this button with the frame of all the other buttons.
Here is a bit of sample code, which should probably go in your view controller because it requires knowledge of the other buttons.

```
- (BOOL) button:(UIButton*)button intersectsWithButtons:(NSArray*)moreButtons
{
    CGRect buttonFrame = button.frame;
    for (UIButton *checkButton in moreButtons) {
        if (button != checkButton && CGRectIntersectsRect(buttonFrame, checkButton.frame))
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I have an error here 
if (button != checkButton && CGRectIntersectsRect(buttonFrame, checkButton.frame)
When i'trying to work with checkButton.frame;